# Delta Potential Boundary Conditions on the wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm reading over how the delta function potential problems are solved and I can't really understand the origin of these boundary conditions:

$(1) \,\,\psi \,\,$ is always continuous

$(2) \,\, \dfrac{d\psi}{dx} \,\,$ is continous except at points where the potential is infinite

What is the origin of these BCs and how do they arise?

I see them in Griffiths and McIntyre but there's not an explanation of why these BCs arise or are needed.

I can see why we would need them. If $\psi\,\,$ is discontinuous then the probability amplitude would be discontinuous and we wouldn't have a physically realizable wavefunction that describes what's going on. If the derivative is discontinuous then that means the evolution of the probability amplitude with respect to change in space would be discontinuous and the wavefunction wouldn't then also be a physically realizable scenario.

What I would like to understand is how they are derived?